# SqlDeveloper: ora-12505 TNS listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

#### Info

```
 connection name: ziv 
 username:sys
 password: xxxxxxx
 connection type: basic 
 role: sysdba 
 host name : localhost.localdomain
 port: 1522
 sid: ziv
```

The QUAST is to connect to the database `ziv` using Sql Developer.

This database was created using dbca.

I am new to both Linux and oracle.

What I need to do... ora-12505 ^^

I think the problem is at bash

```
  [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ tnsping ziv1

   TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 
   09-DEC-2015 12:38:44

   Copyright (c) 1997, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

   Used parameter files:
   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


   Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
   Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS =   
  (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1523)))   
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME =  
   ziv1.localdomain)))
   OK (0 msec)
   [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ lssnrctl services
   bash: lssnrctl: command not found
   [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ lsnrctl services

   LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-DEC-2015 
   12:39:59

   Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

   Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
  (HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
   The listener supports no services
   The command completed successfully
```

#### lsnctl status:

I got a 3 LISTENER name LISTENER port 1521 ziv port 1522 ziv1 port 1523

#### lsnrctl start listener:

```
 [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ lsnrctl start listener
 LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-DEC-2015  
 02:15:16
 Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
 TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been  
 started
 [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ lsnrctl status ziv
 LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-DEC-2015    
 02:15:32 
 Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
 Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)  
 (HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1522)))
 STATUS of the LISTENER
 ------------------------
 Alias                     ziv
 Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -  
 Production
 Start Date                10-DEC-2015 02:05:28
 Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 10 min. 4 sec
 Trace Level               off
 Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
 SNMP                      OFF
 Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network  
 /admin/listener.ora
 Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost  
 /ziv/alert/log.xml
 Listening Endpoints Summary...
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522)))
 The listener supports no services
 The command completed successfully
```

OK what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you:

- configure listener properly with `service-name...`,
- then start your listener with `~]# lsnrctl start <listener-name>;`
- and then check status of listener using `~]lsnrctl status <listener-name>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in windows 10 and Oracle19C.
You should try the following ways and one of them may work for you.

Way-1: In windows: use this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOTwdaI_05A): restart services `OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListener` then `OracleServiceORCL`.

Way-2: connect with `system` user password to `sql plus` as shown as:

```
Enter user-name: system/ as sysdba
Enter password: your_password

SQL> shutdown
SQL> startup nomount
SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=4G scope=both;
SQL> alter database mount;
SQL> alter database open;
```

And now check your problem fixed? If no set below code then check again.

```
SQL> alter system set local_listener='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)   (HOST=127.0.0.1) (PORT=1521)))';
```

This work for me.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers on multiple questions.